# rails ajax sql requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to dynamically load SQL results into a table with the ability to narrow search, click categories and through ajax, change the results.

Any documentation or tutorials on this -- or words of wisdom on getting this started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns) on rolling your own. Then you can check out the [sortable_table](http://rubygems.org/gems/sortable_table) plugin/gem and just use that. You'll have to add your own filter row, but that's pretty easy, it's just a simple form.